# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, reactstrap

I'm trying to use `react-router` with `reactstrap` with `create-react-app`.

In the routing page, I needed to use state for the `reactstrap`, so I converted the router from a variable to a class, but I get this warning:

> ```
> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
> ```

I don't know what to do. I needed to style the router navigation using `reactstrap`, so I did this:

```
<NavLink
    componentClass={Link}
    href="/contact"
    to="/contact"
    active={location.pathname === '/contact'}
>
    anywords
</NavLink>
```

```
<Navbar dark id="RouterNavbar" expand="md">

    <NavbarBrand id="NavBrand"href="#x">
        <ul>
            {/* a bunch of <li></li> */}
        </ul>
    </NavbarBrand>

    <NavbarToggler id="NavBarToggler" onClick={this.toggle1.bind(this)} />

    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen1} navbar>

    <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>

    <NavItem>
        <NavLink href="#x"><Link id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</Link></NavLink>
    </NavItem>

{/* just more of the above */}
```

Other than a couple of `<li>` coming close to each other at random times, hot reloading not working sometimes, and the warning message I get in the console, nothing bad happens, but when I read about this issue, I found out that I shouldn't do this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This is the code which causing the error,

```
<NavLink href="#x"><Link id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</Link></NavLink>
```

Which is converted to,

```
<a><a></a></a>
```

So you are getting error,

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(…): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>
```

To solve this just use one of the follow,

```
<NavLink id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</NavLink>
```

OR,

```
<Link id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</Link>
```

Comment: Thanx the second one worked but the ui is messed up now which is why i used reactstrap in the first place, is there any way to modify the 2nd one so i can use reactstrap link in it ?

Comment: @Amr If you are not bound to use NavLink from reactstrap only, then "react-router-dom" package itself giving you the NavLink, use import  {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: this didnt solve my error, i am using material ui and i have removed all Link/Nav.link tags and still the error persists

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik Can you provide the working fuddle? Will try to solve your query.

Comment: If you're using React Bootstrap's `Nav.Link` and React Router's `Link` components, you can solve this setting the `Nav.Link`'s `as` property as `div`. Docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/navs/#nav-link-props)

Comment: @ravibagul91 where is None come from ?

Answer (score 26):

Add the `as` prop (formerly `componentClass`) to your original `NavLink` to keep the styling while also silencing the warning.

See [`react-bootstrap#nav-link-props`](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/navs/#nav-link-props) docs

Or [View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IHoA.png)

Original:

```
<NavLink href="#x">
  <Link id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</Link>
</NavLink>
```

New:

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/contact">anywords</Nav.Link>
```

Comment: @AdityaPatnaik, you got to import it from react-router-dom

Comment: Did that, if it were an import issue, it would hv thrown an import error. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest an alternate solution which not only solve your problem but give you desired result. In any case someone else stumbled on this post like I did.

Use Link jsx element offered by react router dom but add `className="nav-link"` to it. This will give you styling of the NavLink jsx which react strap is using.

So, it should look like this,

```
<Link className="nav-link" id="RouterNavLink" style={None} to="/contact">anywords</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this in order to avoid the error

```
<NavItem as="li"> <Link>.....
```

Comment: in typescript it throws error of  Property 'as' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & NavLinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. It is because we can not use link, or a tag inside another like...

```
<a><a></a></a>
```

I wanted to apply className to my a tag in navigation bar. so i applied className to a tag in component and import that component in navigation bar component

```
<a className="nav-link" onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>
    Login
  </a>
```

This is how i use this link in navigation template,without any classname

```
<LoginButton />
```